# Virtualbox very very slow with ubuntu 15

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Windows 8.1 is host, ubuntu 15 is guest.

Starting firefox in ubuntu takes 50 seconds. Add another 30 seconds until I can actually start typing into the address bar.
The ram consumption is only 300 mb of the box, I set it to 1024 mb though.

The installation has 10 GB of fixed hd space.

It literally drives me crazy.

What can I do to speed up things?

Comment: How much ram does the host machine have?

Comment: 6 GB, shows as 5.9 in the task manager

Comment: RAM doesn't appear to be the issue then. How much free space do you have on your host system drive where Windows is installed? Also, do you have more than one hard drive or just one?

Comment: I have just one. There are 50 GB free of the 700 GB

Comment: I'd say that could be part of the problem. Performance can really slow down if you have less than 30-20% free disk space. Any chance you can remove files to free up more space?

Comment: How much of the guest memory is being consumed by Firefox?  Web browsers are notorious memory hogs...

Comment: @Geruta I have 72 gb free now. I booted up, hey cool, 5s to start firefox. I did some other stuff, opened intellij as well while i had firefox closed. Now I reopen firefox. Took 60 seconds.

Comment: do you know if you have virtualization enabled in your bios? Intel is labeled "Intel VT" and AMD is "AMD-V". This option should be set to yes or true.

Comment: @Geruta I checked the task manager when opening firefox. It takes 60 seconds, and the disk jumps to 100% all the time for the oracle virtual box. Is there some tool to defragment the disk or something? I can do it under windows right, but do I have to do it in linux as well seperatly? it's a fresh install though.

Comment: Can you give your VM more disk space? See if you can extend your guest VM out to 40gb instead of 10. Keep in mind that if you  have it thin provisioned (the guest Virtual HD that is), it won't eat up the full 40gb unless you actually put 40gigs worth of stuff on it.

Comment: @Geruta i actually set the size of the disk to be fixed size, I guess that actually forces the file to be a certain size? It took quite a while to setup the 10 gb I gave to it. I read that there can occur problems if not set to fixed size, and I really wanted to avoid that.

Comment: firefox when closed seems to get removed entirely from the box's ram. If i open it again, it takes quite a while to load again. I freed a bit more space, it takes now roughly 15 seconds to open firefox after it was opened before. But it always makes the disk jump to almost max each time i do it

Comment: I don't install Ubuntu all that often, but 10gigs for an OS seems a bit small.  I know its a pain and it may take a while but increasing the HD size might help. Also, like I said earlier, check to make sure the virtualization feature is enabled in your bios.

Comment: virtualization is enabled! I am now getting quite sure there must be something wrong with the memory settings. The memory never! exceeds 200 mb, even with various firefox open, and a whole developer environment. When alt tabbing into firefox, i see heavy 100% disk usage. Alt tabbing! then it goes down and i can use firefox normal. Then I alt-Tab to my intellij environment and again, 100% disk read.